# sum(value) gives undefined index

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having trouble calculating the sum of one column in the database from the first 5 rows. My code is:

```
$mysqli=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$database);
$sql = "SELECT SUM(medie) FROM (SELECT medie FROM stelewar WHERE nume='".$nume."' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5) medie";
$result=mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$sumamedie= $row["medie"];
```

The last row of code throws the error "Undefined index: medie" and I cannot figure out why...
Any thoughts?

Comment: try doing `var_dump($row)` before the last line and check to see what the index the expected data is in. i don't believe the index for the `SUM(medie)` field of your row is going to be `medie`

Comment: Query is most likely failing or no rows returned, etc.

Comment: You've aliased the subquery the same as the column you want to SUM

Comment: Try `SELECT SUM(medie) as medie FROM`

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: In mysql the query works just fine and returns the expected result. The problem is somewhere in the php code... Changing the name of the alias throws the same error. SELECT SUM(medie) as medie throws the error "mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given".

Comment: var dump gives the result: array (size=1)
  'SUM(medie)' => string '12.000' (length=6) and this is the expected result

Comment: PS: sanitizing the query and mysql injection is not a concern for the time being. I will deal with this later.

Comment: I have resolved the issue by splitting the query in 2 parts and doing a foreach in order to calculate the sum.

Answer (score 1):

```
$mysqli=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$database);

    $sql ="(SELECT SUM(media) AS mysumvalue FROM  stelewar WHERE nume='".$nume."' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5)";
        $result=mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
        $sumamedie= $row["mysumvalue"];
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).